# How to use logic checking for derived types in RavenDB indexes?

Tags: c#, ravendb

I need to store different values in the index based on the type of `PriceSetup`.

I've tries the code below.

I've alos tried specyfing the fully qualifies class name.

In both cases RavenDB tell me that is could not find the type `FixedPriceSetup` when I try to create the index.

How can I store different values in the index based on type of `PriceSetup`?

```
public class Trade
{
    public PriceSetup PriceSetup;
}

public abstract class PriceSetup
{
    public int TotalPrice;
}

public class FixedPriceSetup : PriceSetup
{
    public int DailyPrice;
}

public class FlexiblePriceSetup : PriceSetup
{
    //...some other stuff
}

public class TradeSearchIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Trade>
{
    public TradeSearchIndex()
    {
        Map = trades =>
            from trade in trades
            select new
            {
                TotalPrice = trade.PriceSetup is FixedPriceSetup
                    ? Math.Abs(trade.PriceSetup.TotalPrice) * Math.Sign((trade.PriceSetup as FixedPriceSetup).DailyPrice)
                    : trade.PriceSetup.TotalPrice
            }
    }
}
```

I would like to keep the index definition in code since the `Trade` class is very complicated and intellisense is a blessing in this case.

Edit:
The code beloew seems to work:

```
public class TradeSearchIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Trade>
{
    public TradeSearchIndex()
    {
        Map = trades =>
            from trade in trades
            select new
            {
                TotalPrice = 
                    AsDocument(trade.PriceSetup)["$type"].ToString() == "RavenTest.FixedPriceSetup, RavenTest"
                        ? Math.Abs(trade.PriceSetup.TotalPrice) * Math.Sign(AsDocument(trade.PriceSetup)["DailyPrice"].Value<int>)
                        : trade.PriceSetup.TotalPrice
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type doesn't exist on the server, which is why you get this error.
However, this is a really good place to use multi map.
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/indexes/multi-map-indexes

Comment: The multimap example from the link you've shared shows how to create a multimap index for different collecitons. In my case all documents are in the same colleciton of type `Trade`. I don't understand how multimap will solve the provlem that I can't use `trade.PriceSetup.DailyPrice` in my index definition.

Comment: Would you be so kind to look at the Edit I've provided and tell me if this will work or is this complety wrong?

Comment: You can map the same collection repeated, and filter based on the metadata property `Raven-Clr-Type`

Comment: how do I filter basen on the metadata property if all documents are of the same type - `Trade`? I think it's not possible.